# Is there a way to share dynamic graphics with various PSDs (update in one place, update everywhere)

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm working on building new site templates for ThemeForest and will have to create multiple template documents for the various page designs. I was wondering if I could, some how, create a shared header and footer graphic that all templates can use. I'm a programmer and dislike code duplication. I don't want to have graphic duplication either, as it'd make things more difficult if I choose to update a template header that is shared with many other templates.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been explored by others, but I am not aware of a flexible, native way to accomplish it.

[Here is one of the best attempts I've seen.](http://www.viget.com/inspire/linked-smart-objects-in-photoshop/)

But as the article says, it has limitations:

> The scripts are only compatible with Photoshop CS4 and CS5, and some technical issues prevent it from working in Windows Vista or Windows 7.
>
> There won't be a perfect solution for linking files in Photoshop until Adobe finally decides to make it a native feature.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Wizard. I was hoping for some native feature that in Photoshop. Perhaps it's something that Adobe will add at another time. For now, the sections of each template I build out, I'll group them up. Then, if I need to change a header, footer, etc., I can grab the folder and copy / paste to the new file. It's not perfect, though it'll work. Thanks for your reply! I'll mark it as my answer as it's the closest answer I'm going to get.

Comment: I agree, using smart object is the best solution. Unfortunately Photoshop can't use other PSDs as part of the design but it can use Illustrator files. It would sure be nice if Adobe decided to add an option to use other file formats within Photoshop just like InDesign, Dreamweaver and After Effects can now. .